# Is there a good Emacs mode or method for lex/flex/yacc/bison files?

Tags: emacs, yacc, lex

Editing lex or yacc files with Emacs is a nuisance: if I use C mode the indenting goes wrong, and if I don't use C mode I can't use indenting. Does anyone have a trick, a method, or an editing mode to get around it?

Comment: Good question! This would be an excellent application for MuMaMo  (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo)

Comment: I don't think that is suited for this problem since it only seems to know about web programming things.

Answer (score 7):

It's not entirely what you want but there is a very excelent Bison mode for Emacs.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BisonMode

This is a better link:

http://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/emacs/elisp-archive/incoming/bison-mode.el.gz

Since Yacc and bison are so closely related I don't find it lacking too much.  Though I do most of my work with Antlr anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Matz (of Ruby fame) wrote a yacc(/bison) mode. Have a look at http://www.rubyist.net/~matz/a/yacc.el

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

http://borkware.com/quickies/single?id=73

or this one

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs19/emacs_26.html#SEC184

Answer (score -4):

I generally toggle between Makefile mode, text mode, and C mode depending on which line I am on.  If you want better, you should write the mode!

Comment: I don't know Emacs lisp so I can't do that.

Comment: When you don't have an answer, why do you tell him to write it by himself? Seriously if I could down vote, I would.

Comment: It's open source software. If you don't like the way it works, you can fix it. That's the whole point of open source software.

Comment: Whoah, tough crowd.